# Difference between DownloadStringTaskAsync & DownloadStringAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc5 web application, and i am not sure what are the differences between using `DownloadStringTaskAsync()`  & using`DownloadStringAsync()` . for example if i have the following webclient :-

```
 using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
 {
     string url = currentURL + "home/scanserver?tokenfromtms=" + "12345" + "&FQDN=allscan" ;
     var json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
     TempData["messagePartial"] = string.Format("Scan has been completed. Scan reported generated");                 
 }
```

will there be any differences if i chnage  DownloadStringTaskAsync(url); to DownloadStringAsync(url); ??

Answer (score 12):

`WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` is using the older [event-based asynchronous pattern (EAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx).

`WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync` is using the newer [task-based asynchronous pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx).

Since your code is already using `async`/`await`, I recommend you stick with the TAP method. TAP code is more maintainable than EAP code.

You could also go another step further and consider using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`. The odd naming in `WebClient` is due to it supporting both synchronous and EAP, and then later updated to include TAP. In contrast, `HttpClient` is a newer type that was based on TAP right from the beginning, so its API is cleaner.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but in both cases the iis will wait to receive the string (download the string) before continue execution ? is this correct??.  for example in the action method (i wrote in my original question)  i will never end up reaching " TempData["messagePartial"] = string.Format("Scan has been completed. Scan reported generated");" line unless the webclient finishes execution (the strinf is fully downloaded)... either using "downloadstringasync" or using  "downloadstringtaskasync" is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, this is how async works. I encourage you to check out the post I wrote that gives a general overview of how async works and does a little myth-busting about things a lot of people think it does that it doesn't. http://cpratt.co/async-not-faster/

Comment: @johnG: The `await` will pause your current method until the string is downloaded. The EAP version (`DownloadStringAsync`) cannot be `await`ed, so your method continues executing immediately while the download is in progress, and the web client notifies you of the download completion via `DownloadStringCompleted`. Note that the `await` code is much easier to write and maintain than event-handling code.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary this is very important note, as in the other reply they mentioned that both will wait for the string to be downloaded ...

Comment: @StephenCleary now i have been working with Async method before, such as SaveChangesAsync() & toListAsync() , etc... and visual studio will always draw a green line if i used any of these Async methods without using the word "await"... and VS will  mentioned that if i do not use "await" then the execution will continue before the current method is completed (so it might raise problems).. but when using DownloadStringTaskAsync, VS will not show any green line to warn about not having "await" before DownloadStringTaskAsync .. so is there a reason for this ?

Comment: @johnG: I'm not sure why the hint isn't showing up. You certainly *should* use `await` with `DownloadStringTaskAsync`, so I'd expect VS to pick up on that...

Comment: @StephenCleary ya strange ,, so if i want to use DownloadStringAsync then there is not any way to force my application to await for the DownloadStringAsync to complete ? as you mentioned that DownloadStringAsync can not be awaited ,, or i can force it to await other than using the word await ?

Comment: @johnG: You *can* wrap the EAP members inside a TAP wrapper, and await that task. But that would be pointless, because `DownloadStringTaskAsync` already does that.

Answer (score 5):

The [DownloadStringTaskAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh194294(v=VS.110).aspx) and [DownloadStringAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation do a pretty good job of highlighting both similarities and differences.

They both are non-blocking, asynchronous methods.  However, `DownloadStringAsync` has a return signature of void and requires you to listen to the `DownloadStringCompleted` event to obtain your results from Result, whereas the `DownloadStringTaskAsync` method returns a `Task<string>`.

The latter is useful if you have parallel asynchronous operations that you need to await before continuing or if you want to call `ContinueWith` on the operation once it's completed.  In addition, with the latter you'll also need to retrieve the result from the task once the task is in a completed state which can be unwrapped with await.

Finally, `DownloadStringAsync` requires a URI whereas `DownloadStringTaskAsync` will accept a string.

For ease of use, `DownloadStringTaskAsync` will probably work just fine, provided that you've placed it in an async method as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var json = GetGoogleFromTask(wc);                
        json.Dump();
    }
}

public async Task<string> GetGoogleFromTask(WebClient wc)
{
    string url = "http://www.google.com" ;
    var json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    return json;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also return just the Task so that you can continue other operations without needing an async method that awaits the return:

```
void Main()
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var json = GetGoogleFromTask(wc);                
        json.Dump();
    }
}

public Task<string> GetGoogleFromTask(WebClient wc)
{
    string url = "http://www.google.com" ;
    var json = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: not sure i got your point so what type of task "DownloadStringTaskAsync"  will return.for example if i am calling a web service that will return a json ,, so how i can work with the return json object as a task ? sorry for asking many questions !!

Comment: @johnG I've clarified my answer since DownloadStringAsync's behavior wasn't quite what I was expected. I've also added examples for how to use DownloadStringTaskAsync.

Comment: Simplistically, whenever you see `*Async` and `*TaskAsync` versions of a method, that means that the `*Async` version predates the introduction of async-await in C#, and used an evented pattern to achieve a similar effect. `*TaskAsync` methods were added after async-await and utilize async-await. The previous methods remain for backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @ChrisPratt so that why i do not have to explicitly write "await" when using DownloadStringTaskAsync ?? and if i explicitly write "await" will it have any deferences ?

Comment: You never *have* to use `await`. There's times where you might actually want to interact with the `Task<T>` object. The `await` keyword is just syntactic sugar that automatically unwraps the task response. It's functionally the same as just doing `MyAsyncTask().Result` (though there's some exception handling rolled in that you wouldn't have just hitting the `Result` property).

Comment: but i have to use await , because if i do not use await i will get a syntax error inside VS ...

Comment: @johnG Chris' point is that you're not FORCED to use await, which is what I was calling out in my second example.  You could actually return the task and retrieve the .Result property from it.  await is simply syntactic sugar.

Comment: @David L but Stephan mentioned in the other reply that using "DownloadStringAsync" will not await for the string to download !! i am confused now..